# How to create a dynamic playlist

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am a new-bee in WP7. I created a custom music player which can play the songs stored in the application's isolated storage space or from MediaGallery. However, I want the application to play songs from public folders so that I can just put a song in the specified folder and then list it in my player and without changing any code, play the song from my player.

Is there any way to do this on WP7 v7.1 emulator?

Comment: @Will maybe you're a litle sensitive, I see no problem with this question

Comment: @yamamoto I think you may be onto something.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "Public folders". But, you can have folders in your IsolatedStorage. Take a look at the [`GetFileNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02ys433%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method, this gives you the list of files in the folder. You can have your media player pull the list and show/play the files.

Comment: Hi, I dont want to copy songs onto my isolated storage. Is there any way I can add songs to MediaLibrary and list them in my player?